# Spark: How to create streaming Dataset with RowEncoder?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have a streaming dataframe, created using spark structured streaming. Like this-

```
val dataStream =
    spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServer)
      .option("subscribe", topic)
      .load()
```

Now, when I try to create a Dataset from `datastream` with an additional column named `newKey`, it gives me following error-

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for org.apache.spark.sql.Row
[error] - field (class: "org.apache.spark.sql.Row", name: "_2")
[error] - root class: "scala.Tuple2"
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for org.apache.spark.sql.Row
- field (class: "org.apache.spark.sql.Row", name: "_2")
- root class: "scala.Tuple2"
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:444)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:820)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:444)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1$$anonfun$8.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1$$anonfun$8.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:624)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:624)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:444)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:820)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:444)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:433)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$.product(Encoders.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.LowPrioritySQLImplicits$class.newProductEncoder(SQLImplicits.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.newProductEncoder(SQLImplicits.scala:34)
```

The code that I am using is as follows:

```
import spark.implicits._
implicit val rowEncoder: ExpressionEncoder[Row] = RowEncoder(dataStream.schema)

val dsStream =
    dataStream
      .select(lit("a").as("newKey"), col("*"))
      .as[(String, Row)]
      .writeStream
      .format("console")
      .start()
```

Can anyone help me resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of the following will work:

- `map`:

  ```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders, Row}
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

  val df = Seq((1L, "a", 4.0)).toDF("x", "y", "z")

  val encoder = Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING, RowEncoder(df.schema))

  df.map(row => ("a", row))(encoder)
  ```
- `select` with `struct` and `as`:

  ```
  df.select(lit("a"), struct(df.columns map col: _*)).as[(String, Row)](encoder)
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But it didn't work for me. I got following exception - `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Try to map struct<newKey:string,key:binary,value:binary,topic:string,partition:int,offset:bigint,timestamp:timestamp,timestampType:int> to Tuple2, but failed as the number of fields does not line up.;`

Comment: The second one worked for me. Not the first one. Thanks!